# SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool Python error

Tags: python, openssl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have written code to analyze each tweet by IBM Watson Tone Analyzer. Initially, the code was working and was able to give the analysis of each of the 1000 tweets in a list in a Json format.  But now a connection error keeps coming up which states:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.eu-gb.tone-analyzer.watson.cloud.ibm.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /instances/148003f6-4092-49e6-bf71-2b48ffd0a55d/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))
```

I'm unable to understand what to do next. Please help.
**(Note: I'm new to Python please excuse for bad code)**

My code:

```
import json
from ibm_watson import ToneAnalyzerV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{API KEY}')
# I replaced with my API key above.
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3(
    version='2017-09-21',
    authenticator=authenticator)
tone_analyzer.set_service_url('{URL}')
# I replaced with the actual URL above.
emotions_score3 = {}
for i in range(len(l3)):
    text = l3[i]
    tone_analysis = tone_analyzer.tone({'text': text},content_type='application/json').get_result()
    tone=json.dumps(tone_analysis, indent=2)    
    jsonParse = json.loads(tone)
    if "document_tone" in jsonParse.keys():
        if jsonParse["document_tone"]["tones"]!=[]:
            length = len(jsonParse["document_tone"]["tones"])
            k = jsonParse["document_tone"]['tones']
            for i in range(length):
                n = k[i]['tone_name']
                lockdown3.append(n)
                if n in emotions_score3:
                    emotions_score3[n] = emotions_score3[n]+k[0]['score']
                else:
                    emotions_score3.update({n:k[0]['score']})     
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue
```

This is what the Json format pf the output which I first got looks like :

```
{
   "document_tone": {
"tones": [
{
"score": 0.73529,
"tone_id": "joy",
"tone_name": "Joy"
},
{
"score": 0.840028,
"tone_id": "tentative",
"tone_name": "Tentative"
}
]
},
"sentences_tone": [
{
"sentence_id": 0,
"text": "learn to live like hanuman jee, in this lock-down.",
"tones": [
{
"score": 0.724236,
"tone_id": "analytical",
"tone_name": "Analytical"
},
{
"score": 0.5538,
"tone_id": "tentative",
"tone_name": "Tentative"
 }
]
}
]
}
"""
```

Comment: did you manage to solve it? i'm having the very same problem and i'm going a bit desperate about finding a solution

Comment: If you go check your service status in your cloud account, it would probably show that this particular service is inactive. What I did was deactivate it and created that once again. But after some time of use, it will again create this problem so for that you need to suspend the execution of the thread for say 5 seconds (using **time.sleep()**) after every 3 iterations (don't keep the service running continuously as the data keeps coming). This is what helped me.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tejaswi i already tried adding a `time.sleep` but sometimes i get the error in the very first execution so no sleep can help here. Do you have any suggestions about that?

Comment: Create a new service I would say and I think you've got to not use it for a while I guess xD. Yes, this happened to me as well. I did not use it for a while like a day or two and then created a new service and then it worked. I don't have an exact solution but hope this helps and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Going from working to not working might suggest that you have exceeded your monthly lite allowance for the service, but that would manifest itself as a different error.

The SSL Error you are getting is common when the SSL libraries on your client machine become out of date. If you haven't installed anything like openssl, and are using a virtual environment to isolate your application, then the openssl dependancy will be coming from your application dependancies, notably ibm_watson.

You should force a pip update, with no caching, of all your application dependancies.